# New Meta site's newsletter subscribe broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, newsletter

If you go to the [network newsletters page](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters), the new Meta is there:

[image: Meta site newsletter subscribe button]

but the button doesn't work. Which is two bugs really:

1. the subscription doesn't work: the AJAX call is returning the [Oops! page](https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/newsletters/subscribe)
2. the page itself doesn't report the error.

Thanks. Latest Chrome and IE. Glad to see the 'Oops!' page is still the panda!

---

This might now be fixed: the button has gone, and I'm now subscribed to Meta.SE instead of Meta.SO.

Are we losing the Meta.SO newsletter? I can't find it to subscribe back to :-( Or will we get Meta.SO included on the regular SO newsletter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta Stack Overflow will no longer have a newsletter because it now behaves just as any other child meta site. We don't do newsletters for child metas.

Meta Stack Exchange has its own newsletter because it's treated as a "main" site in our code; and it makes more sense that people might want weekly digests from this site, since it isn't directly tied to another community. You may not be interested enough to check *everything* happening here, but might like to see the highlights.

If you still want to receive MSO questions by email, your best bet is to head to https://stackexchange.com/filters and create a new filter for "All questions" on Meta Stack Overflow (you'll have to click "show meta sites" to see that as an option). We don't have a weekly option for those filter emails, but it gets you to the same place: a feed of meta questions to your email inbox.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to see it go, but thank you for pointing me to filters for the work-around.